# Garbage collection high promotion rates

Tags: .net, wpf

I am seeing a high promotion rate of gen 1 objects. When I launch a window in my app, all objects in gen 1 are promoted to gen 2. I believe it is happening due to calling `InitializeComponent()`. If I comment this line out, objects are not promoted to gen 2. Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: Adding some relevant code would go a long way!

Comment: What does the window look like? Many controls? Is the App running any other initialisation code?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx):

> Objects that are not reclaimed in a garbage collection are known as
>   survivors, and are promoted to the next generation. Objects that
>   survive a generation 0 garbage collection are promoted to generation
>   1; objects that survive a generation 1 garbage collection are promoted
>   to generation 2; and objects that survive a generation 2 garbage
>   collection remain in generation 2. When the garbage collector detects
>   that the survival rate is high in a generation, it increases the
>   threshold of allocations for that generation, so the next collection
>   gets a substantial size of reclaimed memory. The CLR continually
>   balances two priorities: not letting an application's working set get
>   too big and not letting the garbage collection take too much time

So what happens I think is that initially threshold is rather low and `InitializeComponent` trigger considerable amount of allocations forcing at least two collections (so promoting first objects to gen 2). Probably GC will detect it and increase threshold and after objects will not get to gen 2 that easily. So basically it looks like artefact of early phase of app lifecycle (when things are being adjusted).

The main question here is if it is a problem for your application? Do you have performance issues? Or anything else? Or it is just out of curiosity?

My hypothesis can be easily verified (or debunked) by using Performance Monitor, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx). You just look at the counters and see what happens. Just see how many collections happen in generations and what is the survival rate.

Comment: Yes we have performance issues, because all of our objects get promoted to gen 2 and when a full gc occurs, the system becomes unresponsive for a few minutes. I understand gen 2 collections are expensive. I am trying to see if there is a way to avoid objects being promoted to gen2 that early in the lifecycle.

Comment: @user2720165 what about trying to avoid creating too many objects before InitializeComponent?

Comment: That's a good point. Just out of curiosity, why is InitializeComponent() creating that many objects?

Comment: @user2720165 because it does a lot of things, it loads all components. It is heavy function indeed. Another option is to try switching to concurrent GC, it should not hang your app in theory.

Comment: @user2720165 you can always just do InitializeComponent() then show some waiting screen and in a meanwhile create all your objects.